# shell script stops proceeding inside the loop

Tags: bash, shell

Using bash version 5, I have a loop that goes through a list, and uses each item in that list in a find command inside the loop,  and then append that find result to an empty array.

This code however stops at saving 1st result successfully in `pid` and script exits. I have tried `trap` and `set -x` with no progress.

Anyone understands what's happening here ?

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -o pipefail
set -vx

## run cleanup on signal 1, 2, 3, 6
trap cleanup 1 2 3 6

cleanup()
{
  echo "Caught Signal $? ... cleaning up."
}

r=$(cat /proc/net/tcp |grep " 01 " |awk '{print $10}')
inodes=()
inodes+=($r)
pattern="^.*(proc)\/\K([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)(?=\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?"

con_pids=()

for inode in ${inodes[*]}
do
        echo inode number is: $inode
        pid=$(find /proc/* -type l -ls 2>/dev/null |grep "socket:\[$inode\]" | grep -m1 -oP $pattern)
        echo "code didn't stop"
        # echo $?
        con_pids+=($pid)
        #con_pids=(${con_pids[*]} "$pid")
done

echo ${con_pids[*]}
```

Comment: Always start with https://shellcheck.net

Comment: You realize that if `grep` doesn't find anything, `set -e` will cause your loop to stop?

Comment: `set -e` is a bad idea for lots of reasons beyond that too -- see [BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105); if you don't have the time to read the anecdote, at least skip down to the exercises and go through them.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy edited question `grep` does find things and saves in the var.

Comment: Also, `${array[*]}` is only for use in unusual special-case scenarios. In almost every case, `"${array[@]}"` is more correct.

Comment: Does it save things in the var **through every single iteration of the loop**, though? If it's missing any inode that gets grepped for, there's your bug.

Comment: Also, don't use `2>/dev/null` until you _know_ your code is bug-free; it's an easy way to hide your real problems. (Not all versions of `find` support `-ls`, f/e; if you were running a script built for GNU tools on a system with busybox, that could cause the failure on its own).

Comment: Also, a pipeline component can have output _and_ have a nonzero exit status; so the fact that there was output doesn't tell us with certainty that no command in the pipeline failed. Indeed, the exit tells us with certainty that something in the pipeline _did_ fail.

Comment: If you comment out `set -e` and then log the `PIPESTATUS` array after the assignment where the exit occurs (`declare -p PIPESTATUS >&2`), that would be helpful.

Comment: BTW, `cat /proc/net/tcp |grep " 01 " |awk '{print $10}'` would be more efficiently written as `awk '/ 01 / { print $10 }' </proc/net/tcp`.

Comment: it was indeed `set -e`,  thank you so much !  will definitely go through the links you posted @CharlesDuffy,  anything links for `PIPESTATUS` ?

Comment: See the [PIPESTATUS](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PIPESTATUS) section in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

Comment: If you use `set -e` (aka `set -o errexit`) it's a *very* good idea to set up an `ERR` trap to show what has happened, and `set -o errtrace` (aka `set -E`) so it fires in functions and subshells etc.  A basic `ERR` trap can be set up with `trap 'printf "ERROR: ERR trap: line %s\\n" "$LINENO" >&2' ERR`.  This will prevent the classic `set -o errexit` problem: the program stops suddenly, at an unknown place, and for no obvious reason.